# Weird bug in Firefox using disabled="disabled"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I nibbling on a bug in ff:

See http://nocturne.wmw.cc/bugff.html (not reproducable in jsfiddle - too bad)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <button disabled="disabled">sdf</button>
 <script>
  jQuery(function(){
    if(!jQuery('button').is(':disabled'))
      alert('Is not disabled!');
    jQuery('button').removeAttr('disabled');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the Problem:

1. If i load the first time, everything is ok.
2. If i reload the page using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, the `alert()` shows the error-message.
3. If i Reload using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> the bug does not occoure.

I do use Microsoft® Windows® 7.
Reproduceable at least at FF28, FF29.

How to solve?

Comment: No, i do not get any error in console!

Comment: So... do you have a question?

Comment: @Satpal Same problem. Hey, `is(':disabled')` != `prop('disabled')`. Please do not make wild guesses mate.

Comment: @PeterRader, Don't be rude I know very well what I suggested and `jQuery('button').prop('disabled') == true` and `jQuery('button').is(':disabled')` will provide you equivalent result

Comment: di you try to add a `$(document).ready()` may the script is executed from cache

Comment: @ekans `jQuery( function() {..} )` is the same as `$(document).ready( function() {..} )`.

Comment: @ekans Yes, i tried `ready()` too, anyway darling, all the script needs has already been loaded at the line 8.

Comment: Are you using this exact code? Because it's missing the closing script tag

Comment: @Satpal sometimes they differs, depends on doctype! strict may not accept `disabled="sure"` as an `:disabled` state.

Comment: @MatteoRiva Yes, exactly this code. You can folow the link, its right there.

Comment: Why -1, why off-topic?

Comment: This is a genuine bug. I agree with @PeterRader for *Why -1, why off-topic?* One more thing peter can put your script in head section

Comment: @Satpal Thanks, sorry for rudeness.

Comment: @PeterRader, peter can put your script in head section. I don't see head section. to be clear `<head><script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script></head>`

Comment: @PeterRader then you might want to add the closing script tag

Comment: @MatteoRiva Oh, you are right, question was wrong, fixed->still occoures.

Comment: @Satpal I add the header-tag around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be the same mechanism that stores user-input for form-elements, the state of the button has been cached.

possible solution(see: [How can I stop Firefox from caching the contents of a textarea on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729360/how-can-i-stop-firefox-from-caching-the-contents-of-a-textarea-on-localhost) ):

```
<button disabled="disabled" autocomplete="off">sdf</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4ZLd9/show/

Comment: Hm, i realy dont know what a `disabled` should be autocompleated; anyway i think you fixed the bug: http://nocturne.wmw.cc/bugff-try2.html

Answer (score 0):

Just try disabled instead of disabled = "disabled"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <button disabled>sdf</button>
    <script>
      jQuery(function(){
        if(!jQuery('button').is(':disabled'))
         alert('Is not disabled!');
       jQuery('button').removeAttr('disabled');
      });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Locally working for me, can you copy source and try locally.
If you check code in firebug there you can see there is no disabled attribute, and if edit code in firebug it will disable the button

Comment: What ff version do you use?

Comment: Did you deactivate chronik or something?